# Trouble With Space Between Accordion FAQs

Tags: html, css

I'm having some frustrating trouble with my FAQ accordions at the bottom of the [following page](http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html).
I need to put about 50px of space in between them, but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please add your generated code and its css

Comment: I tried to get a JS fiddle going, but it uses JS which doesn't do well there - I thought the site link would give everything necessary.

Comment: EDIT: here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Kvz/

Comment: @erndenson PLEASE add a code in this site and remove your broken link

Comment: What do you mean @Omar? I did not put any links - neither working nor broken - here

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your css:

```
 .accordionButton {
    margin: 25px auto;
 }
.accordionContent p { 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    margin-top: 0; 
}
div.accordionContent { 
    margin-top: -25px; 
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems that will also add the same space above the answer to the FAQ, I'd like it to be under that. Here's the JSFiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Kvz/

Comment: @user3517583, i have edited my answer with additional css to bring the FAQ answer higher up closer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Wrap each question and answer in a `div` in my example I've given it a class `container`

Step 2: Remove `float:left` from your styles

Step 3: Add margin-bottom to the `container`

```
.container {margin-bottom:50px;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Kvz/2/

For a tidier more semantic version please see: http://jsfiddle.net/VyzqR/. This uses CSS for the hover effect instead of javascript. Feel free to replace th `h2` tag with what ever `hx` tag mages the most sense for your document layout, just  don't use `h1`!

You may also want to investigate [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)s for your background images. This will reduce filcker while the images load on hover or click.